# How to Get Variable/Feature Importance From Tidymodels ranger object?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyverse, feature-selection, tidymodels

I have a ranger object from the tidymodels rand_forest function:

```
rf <- rand_forest(mode = "regression", trees = 1000) %>% fit(pay_rate ~ age+profession)
```

I want to get the feature importance of each variable (I have many more than in this example). I've tried things like `rf$variable.importance`, or `importance(rf)`, but the former returns `NULL` and the latter function doesn't exist. I tried using the `vip` package, but that doesn't work for a ranger object. How can I extract feature importances from this object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `importance = "impurity"` when you set the engine for ranger. This will provide variable importance scores. Once this is set, you can use `extract_fit_parsnip` with `vip` to plot the variable importance.

small example:

```
library(tidymodels)
library(vip)

rf_mod <- rand_forest(mode = "regression", trees = 100) %>% 
  set_engine("ranger", importance = "impurity")
  
rf_recipe <- 
  recipe(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars) 

rf_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_model(rf_mod) %>% 
  add_recipe(rf_recipe)


rf_workflow %>% 
  fit(mtcars) %>% 
  extract_fit_parsnip() %>% 
  vip(num_features = 10)
```

More information is available in the tidymodels [get started guide](https://www.tidymodels.org/start/)

Comment: What are the other options for `importance`? I saw `"permutation"`, but that's it

Comment: @Adam_G, the `importance` options don't come from `set_engine`, but from `ranger`. And the importance options in ranger are: 'none’, ’impurity’, ’impurity_corrected’, or ’permutation’. More details about these are found in the details section of the help that is available with the `ranger` function.

Comment: Maybe obvious to you but not to me, there is no function "ranger" in the "parsnip" package.  Documentation for all the engines are in their respective packages, in this case "ranger::ranger()."

Comment: ALSO note that the returned fitted model is a parsnip model object, not a ranger object so functions from ranger to examine the result won't work.  It would be nice to be able to cast parsnip results back to the class of the engine that generated it.